# Why were flags on these conversational/argumentative comments declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation, comments

[Stack Exchange guidance on the use of comments](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) specifies

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Specifically called out as *not* appropriate for comments is *"Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point"*. And yet, when I flagged these three comments:

[image]

All three flags were declined.

These comments seem not to fit into the Stack Exchange rules for the user of comments even simply in terms of the types of situations comments are intended for. In addition, the comments may be construed as hostile, especially the one accusing the other person of having a "sense of entitlement" (generally not considered a complimentary remark). All three certainly involve *"debating a controversial point"*, something that is specifically warned *against* by Stack Exchange.

I would appreciate the moderator who declined these flags explaining what it was about those comments that they felt fit within the usual Stack Exchange guidelines for the use of comments, such that the perceived value of the comments outweighed the nominally unsuitable nature of them.

Comment: This is a clear case of "No Longer Needed", but various site mod teams vary widely in how important they feel comment rules need to be enforced. Some site mod teams even commit to not deleting *any* comment that isn't overtly rude/offensive, even if it is only saying something like "+1 thanks".

Comment: @TylerH: okay, but if that's the case here, I'd like the moderator(s) to say so specifically, and there should be some _official_ presentation of that guidance, instead of just rejecting flags when they come up.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sure, I am hoping for a moderator response too; I'm just offering some context from experience across the network.